# Error signing in to gmail this morning

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, openpop

I have a C# app using OpenPop, sending E-Mails through GMAIL.
This app has been working for the last few years, without a problem, and the last EMAIL I got from it was 8 hours ago.
Now I get an 'InvalidLoginException' error when I try to log in. I logged in normally to my account, even tried to change passwords but I still get this same message.
Following previous tips I tried to change the login line from

```
pop3Client.Authenticate(EMAIL_ADDRESS, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD) to 
pop3Client.Authenticate(EMAIL_ADDRESS, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword)
```

But I still get the same message.
Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have to log into your google account and create an app password for you to continue to send emails

Comment: No idea how and why, but somehow it looks OK now.I think that the fact I disabled and re-enabled the POP3 in my account did the trick.